# ROS Answers SE migration: osg missing?

Tags: ros, rosmake, uwsim, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to use [UWSim](http://ros.org/wiki/UWSim) and did eveything on the webpage. The problem now is that when I do:

```
rosmake UWSim --rosdep-install
```

I get the following error:

```
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build
  cd build && make -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/UWSim
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libosg.so.65, needed by /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libosgUtil.so.65, needed by /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libosgDB.so.65, needed by /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libosgGA.so.65, needed by /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libOpenThreads.so.13, needed by /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
  /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so: undefined reference to `OpenThreads::Mutex::Mutex()'
  /home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/osgOcean/lib/libosgOcean.so: undefined reference to `osgDB::readImageFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, osgDB::ReaderWriter::Options const*)'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/UWSim] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/UWSim.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/albert/ros_electric/underwater_simulation/UWSim/build'
```

From which I asume osg lib is missing. I've checked on google how to install it but no result found.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve it??

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35895/osg-missing?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you recently upgrade your distro? You have installed openscenegraph 3.0, which should link against libosg.so.80. However, your osgOcean seems to be compiled against libosg.so.65. Have you tried to pre-clean your build?

rosmake --pre-clean UWSim

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-06-07**:
it worked! thanks mario

**Comment by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) on 2012-06-07**:
great! you're welcome